# Getting VT-X is not available inside CENTOS7 guest

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7, virtualization

I have currently got a CENTOS7 guest inside windows 10 host and I am trying to install vagrant and Virtual box inside the CENTOS guest to create a kubernetes cluster for local development.

I have installed vagrant 2.1.1 and VirtualBox 5.2.12

When I am trying to

> vagrant up

It says **VT-X is not available**.

I have **turned on Virtualization in BIOS** and I have checked windows features and **HyperV is disabled/unchecked**.

Also when I cat the */proc/cpuinfo* , vmx is not in the flags

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 3092.984
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips        : 6185.96
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Also for the *lscpu* command :

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               3092.984
BogoMIPS:              6185.96
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

I would really appreciate any insight on how I can get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You disabled hyper-v, this means that you are using alternative hypervisor(virtualbox?). I don't think that anything except hyper-v on windows supports nested virtualization.

You can give a try to hyper-v guest with centos(with enabled nested virtualization by command `Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`) and run virtualbox with vagrant inside it.